# Unir 3 o más consultas en SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una consulta que hacerles con respecto a SQL Server 2012, tengo una tabla `PREMIOS_DATA`,  de esta tabla obtengo los resultados del MES ACTUAL con la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT MES = datename(MONTH,GETDATE()), c1.GESTION AS CAMPAÑA, c1.ASESOR as ASESOR, COLOCACION, ISNULL(ASISTENCIA, '') AS ASISTENCIA, PROMEDIO = (COLOCACION/ASISTENCIA), FECHA_CALL =convert(varchar, getdate(), 103)FROM (
    SELECT GESTION, ASESOR, SUM(VENTAS) as COLOCACION
      FROM PREMIOS_DATA
        WHERE FECHA_GESTION >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(103),DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1)),103) and FECHA_GESTION <= getdate()
        group by GESTION, ASESOR
  ) c1 left JOIN (
    SELECT GESTION, ASESOR, SUM(ASISTENCIA) AS ASISTENCIA
      FROM PREMIOS_DATA 
        WHERE FECHA_GESTION >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(103),DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1)),103) and FECHA_GESTION <= convert(varchar, getdate(), 103)
        group by GESTION, ASESOR 
  ) c2 ON c1.ASESOR=c2.ASESOR
 ORDER by PROMEDIO DESC
```

Esta consulta funciona muy bien, pero necesito sacar en la misma consulta los registros del mes anterior con respecto al mes actual, es decir que Del mismo `ASESOR` me despliegue en la misma línea - `COLOCACION y ASISTENCIA` - del `MES` que ya pasó.

De antemano agradezco mucho sus ideas y sugerencias al respecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta con utilizar la sentencia "union"

```
SELECT MES = datename(MONTH,GETDATE()), c1.GESTION AS CAMPAÑA, c1.ASESOR as ASESOR, COLOCACION, ISNULL(ASISTENCIA, '') AS ASISTENCIA, PROMEDIO = (COLOCACION/ASISTENCIA), FECHA_CALL =convert(varchar, getdate(), 103)FROM (
    SELECT GESTION, ASESOR, SUM(VENTAS) as COLOCACION
      FROM PREMIOS_DATA
        WHERE FECHA_GESTION >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(103),DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1)),103) and FECHA_GESTION <= getdate()
        group by GESTION, ASESOR
  ) c1 left JOIN (
    SELECT GESTION, ASESOR, SUM(ASISTENCIA) AS ASISTENCIA
      FROM PREMIOS_DATA 
        WHERE FECHA_GESTION >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(103),DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1)),103) and FECHA_GESTION <= convert(varchar, getdate(), 103)
        group by GESTION, ASESOR 
  ) c2 ON c1.ASESOR=c2.ASESOR
 ORDER by PROMEDIO DESC
UNION
SELECT MES = datename(MONTH,GETDATE()), c1.GESTION AS CAMPAÑA, c1.ASESOR as ASESOR, COLOCACION, ISNULL(ASISTENCIA, '') AS ASISTENCIA, PROMEDIO = (COLOCACION/ASISTENCIA), FECHA_CALL =convert(varchar, getdate(), 103)FROM (
    SELECT GESTION, ASESOR, SUM(VENTAS) as COLOCACION
      FROM PREMIOS_DATA
        WHERE FECHA_GESTION >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(103),DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE())),103) and FECHA_GESTION <= getdate()
        group by GESTION, ASESOR
  ) c1 left JOIN (
    SELECT GESTION, ASESOR, SUM(ASISTENCIA) AS ASISTENCIA
      FROM PREMIOS_DATA 
        WHERE FECHA_GESTION >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(103),DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE())),103) and FECHA_GESTION <= convert(varchar, getdate(), 103)
        group by GESTION, ASESOR 
  ) c2 ON c1.ASESOR=c2.ASESOR
 ORDER by PROMEDIO DESC
```

En la primera obtendrás la del mes anterior y en la segunda la del mes actual.

Comment: Gracias Max.. lo probaré y te comento a ver que tal me fue

Comment: De acuerdo. Estaré al tanto por cualquier apoyo adicional